# Windows 7 laptop showing network as unidentified

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a Dell precision 4800 Laptop which is most of the time hooked up to the LAN at the users desk. Out on our production floor we have 4 Access Points, each on their own VLAN except for 1 which shares the 192.168.0.* network with the rest of the main domain.

When the user takes his laptop out to the Access Point and connects the computer says it is connected to an unidentified network and it gets an IP from the DHCP server successfully but it cannot see any other devices on the network. The IP that it gets is the IP that he gets when connected to the LAN.

When he connects to another AP he gets his DHCP address for that VLAN (192.168.4.*) and is able to connect to the network and email and internet just fine.

When I take another computer out there to the floor and connect to the wifi it gets the same IP as if connected to the LAN and it works just fine. Able to surf the web, connect to network drives, everything.

I tried netsh int ip reset and everything I can think of but this one PC, on this 1 network, will not connect properly and I am confused as hell.

All of the AP's are up to date with the latest firmware and they are all the same model, Pakedge W7

Comment: This limited to a single user?  Just to clarify, and please clarify this yourself, if I am correct.  User connects to an access point, is assigned an ip address but Windows identifies it as a "unidentified network" once this same user connected to a different access point everything works as expected.

Comment: No it happens across all users

Comment: That is correct.  The issue with the Access Point on the .0 network is that it is giving him an IP address which is valid and I have tested with other IP's and get the same results but when connecting to the Access Point on the .4 network he gets a new .4 address and gets out to the network and internet just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a networking issue because all users connected to that AP don't get internet.

Can you post the IP address, subnet mask, and default gateway for the .0 and .4 APs? I have a feeling the .0 AP isn't set up correctly.

Also VLANs can be a pain. What router are you using and is it set up for VLANs?

Comment: I would love to add a comment, but I don't have enough rep yet. Maybe help me out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response.  I did end up getting this resolved but not the way I would think.  So I talked to Dell because the computer is still under warranty and they were obsessed with the fact that it was an issue with my network.  I continued telling them it was not so they sent me out a replacement card and it did the exact same thing.

So what I did was I took another wireless card out of a similar model computer except it was an Intel brand and not a Dell brand.  I put it in this computer, loaded the drivers, took it out to the floor and immediately it connected without any issue.  Everything worked perfect.

After complaining to Dell for a while I got them to send me out a replacement card but this time it was an Intel brand.  Got it and installed it and immediately starting working perfectly.  I have not had a single issue since.  Dell later admitted their wireless cards are trash.